# SQL Select Distinct deciding which record to keep

Tags: sql, visual-studio

I've got a query that lists people who haven't yet passed an assessment, and want to add a column to show whether they've attempted it or not. If they've not attempted it, the field is `null`, and if they have made an attempt it shows `failed`. I've got this to show up from the relevant assessment tables, but when a person has a `failed` it also shows another row for them with nothing in the status column (this is because they can pass one of 2 courses, so there may be a record for having failed one and not accessed the other). I'm using `select distinct` on my main query. I understand why I can't use `distinct` on just some columns as it won't know which of the records to show.

Is there any way I can use either SQL or an expression in Visual Studio to merge the two, ensuring the `failed` status is preserved? It only needs to be done for the benefit of this report so it doesn't matter if it's in Visual Studio.

```
ID    firstname    surname    lessonstatus
------------------------------------------
27    joe          bloggs      
47    mickey       mouse
47    mickey       mouse      Failed
```

What I want it to show is as follows:

```
ID    firstname    surname    lessonstatus
------------------------------------------
27    joe          bloggs      
47    mickey       mouse      Failed
```

In the database Mickey Mouse is in the database twice, once for each of the two courses, but for the purposes of this report I don't need to show the course, I only need to show their name in the list once as having not passed either of them. If they've failed, I want to preserve the `Failed` entry as an indication that at least they've made an attempt at one or other of the two courses

Comment: Please provide the schema, sample data, and desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to answer without the table layouts, but assuming you have assessment tables with the stame structure, this should do the trick:

```
SELECT ID, firstname, surname, MAX(lessonstatus) FROM(
    SELECT * FROM assessment1
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM assessment2
) GROUP BY ID, firstname, surname
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. In my case they're in the same table, for the benefit of others, if the results are in the same table the above can be change so that they both select from the same `assessment` table, but using `where` to choose the two assessments. In fact for my existing query, all I needed to do was `MAX(lessonstatus)` and then `GROUP BY` the other fields in my `select` statement

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will provide what you need.

```
select p.name
, coalesce(a.value, 'no attempt') result
from person p left join assessment a on a.personId = p.personID
and a.value <> 'pass'
etc
```

You'll need your own table names of course.  Also, all filtering on the assessment table has to be done in the from clause.  If you try it in the where clause, the join becomes inner.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this doesn't seem to omit the second occurrence of the person